# Change locale when the initiliazition is in external file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I am using Vue3 and vue-i18n. I have a file called i18n.js located where are the App.vue file and main.js. In this file i have initialized the component like this:

```js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import translations from '@/translation.js';
    
const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: '', // It's empty because i want to set it in App.vue
  fallbackLocale: 'de', 
  translation,
});

export default i18n;
```

Then i can import this file and use the i18n.global.t('translation.KEY');
But it's never switch the language. It always de=Deutsch.
In my App.vue file i am reading client settings from a file and on the mounted section after i read it i am setting the locale like this:

```js
mounted() { 
  this.$i18n.locale = this.$store.getters['settings'].language; 
}
```

Also in the settings tab on change of multiselect i am changing it and save it to file. But it's not working. Always shows the Deutsch text. If I remove the fallbackLocale it displays:
*translation.KEY....*

Is there any solution of this problem?

**main.js**

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import i18n from './config.js';

const app = createApp(App); 
app.use(i18n); 
app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your syntax it looks like you're still using Options API. Simply set `legacy` option to true

```js
const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: true,
  ...
});
```

Assigning to `this.$i18n.locale` will work. Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-i18n-forked-vsm8v3?file=/src/main.js) if you'd like to see a full working example.

Comment: It is not working. I initialize the vue-i18n in the i18n.js file. I think the problem is because the vue-i18n is initialized before App.vue is loaded.

Comment: in terms of loading order, plugins _should_ load first before the root component does (when the app mounts itself).  it's ok to initialize the plugin in another file, as long as it's imported to main.js and installed via `app.use(i18n)`.  Include in your question your main.js file and more of your App.vue file showing the context for where/how `$i18n.locale = ` is happening.

Comment: main.js:
`import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import i18n from './config.js';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(i18n);

app.mount('#app');`

App.vue
`mounted() {
this.$i18n.locale = this.$store.getters['settings'].language;
}`

Comment: Questions are editable so you can add additional (formatted) code there.  I've editted it for you this time.  What is the value returned by `this.$store.getters['settings'].language`?  Have you verified what that value is with something like a console.log?

Comment: Thank you. 
The returned value is correct - 'English' or 'Deutsch' - it depends what is the user choise. It get it from a file where i am saving the client settings.

Comment: Those are not the values you should use when setting `$i18n.locale`, it needs to be the language code, e.g. `en` or `de`.

Comment: In my translation file i am using 'English' and 'Deutsh'.

Comment: instead of naming it `translations` you should import and use `messages`.  It's important to use the correct config option name, e.g. `createI18n({ messages })`

Comment: Same thing when i am using messages and en/de for the locale

Comment: I noticed that i have one more problem and maybe they are connected. When i import the i18n in my vuex store and use it mutations or actions it works(it shows the translation and i can change the locale) but if i am using it before the store is created, its not working. In my case i have a object with options names which is declared before the store is created.

Comment: Does anyone have another solution?